# Heroku: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" SpringBoot Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

After i deployed the the spring from github. i got this log :

```
> 2022-10-12T18:20:15.550627+00:00 app[web.1]:        Syntax: -Akey=value
2022-10-12T18:20:15.550628+00:00 app[web.1]:        Default: {}
2022-10-12T18:20:15.550628+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-10-12T18:20:15.688794+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-10-12T18:20:15.810897+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-10-12T18:20:16.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-10-12T18:20:20.932826+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cexjava.herokuapp.com request_id=55635bbb-091d-4f2b-851d-5517bc7827ca fwd="203.205.41.247" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-12T18:20:21.385791+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=cexjava.herokuapp.com request_id=e111312d-8775-418e-b00b-c3b754d1d860 fwd="203.205.41.247" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-12T18:20:28.502538+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cexjava.herokuapp.com request_id=ca8c9a75-b4f9-4ec9-b9d7-c25ee4355c20 fwd="203.205.41.247" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-12T18:20:28.877105+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=cexjava.herokuapp.com request_id=d41eb599-49f1-4dea-a4d7-2f8e52b1f1ce fwd="203.205.41.247" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I have tried many ways.
1: in the application.properties add `server.port=${PORT:8080}`

2: add Procfile :
web:     `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/CexToolSever-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=$PORT $JAR_OPTS` or     `web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war`

Comment: in spring boot can you enable debug logging with `logging.level.org.springframework=debug`
as these logs are not very helpful to analyse issue

Comment: i did but it still not show any thing but:
the code h10 as above